# Setting ID for Spinner items

Tags: android, spinner

I have an array of Strings I'm populating a Spinner object with.  However, I'd like to attach an ID to each element of the Spinner, so when the user selects an item, I have its ID to use to save to some other piece of data.  How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand, spinner or array position are not enough to use as an id?

Comment: It's an ID specific to the item in the Spinner.  It could be 1; it could be 93847549387925187.  It's a database primary key.

Comment: Andrew i have the same problem...if you have got the Answer to your question than please help me to....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What do you mean by id. You can use ArrayAdapter to populate the Spinner. When item is selected just get the element from the adapter and save the data you want.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = ... // initialize the adapter
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.some_view);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and when item is selected

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    MyObject selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    // save any data relevant with selected item   
}
```

If you are storing your data in db you can use CursorAdapter and in onItemSelected to fetch the selected item id from the cursor.

Comment: If I use a CursorAdapter, how do I tell it that the "name" column is for the text that shows up in the list?

Answer (score 47):

Create a class StringWithTag and use in place of the string name in the list like so :-

```
public class StringWithTag {
    public String string;
    public Object tag;

    public StringWithTag(String stringPart, Object tagPart) {
        string = stringPart;
        tag = tagPart;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

in the add items to spinner part :-

```
List<StringWithTag> list = new ArrayList<StringWithTag>();
list.add(new StringWithTag("Oldman", "12345"));
list.add(new StringWithTag("Umpire", "987654"));
list.add(new StringWithTag("Squad", "ABCDEE"));
ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> adap = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
....
....
```

in the listener :-

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parant, View v, int pos, long id) {
    StringWithTag s = (StringWithTag) parant.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    Object tag = s.tag;
}
```

voila!
    }

Comment: @Robert... err... StringWithTag is something created as in the first block of code above.

Comment: This solution is elegant and perfect! This also implement Spinner key value like HTML <select>

Comment: Worked well. I always prefer a built in structure, however android is lacking one in this regard.

Comment: Why is `toString` marked `@Override` when `StringWithTag ` is not inheriting anything?

Comment: @Violet, all classes inherit from Object and toString is a method inherited from Object

Comment: In the listener :  `parant` should be `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can attach an arbitrary ID to elements of a text array resource, if that's what you're using.

I think the simplest way to attach such an ID would be to either hard-code (if you're using a static text resource) or dynamically build (if you get the strings at runtime) a mapping from (String position in array)->(primary key).

EDIT: On the other hand, Mojo Risin has a point - you should check to see if the CursorAdapter API already does what you need for you.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Hi, it's been a long time but it's worth to write.

You can set a tag for each row when you'r inflating **spinnerLayout** in **SpinnerAdapter**:

```
spinnerView = inflater.inflate(spinnerLayout, parent, false);
spinnerView.setTag("Your Tag");
```

And then you can get the tag with:

```
yourSpinner.getSelectedView().getTag();
```

Answer (score -2):

I think The best solution is to add one more spinner and fill it with the ids but make the visibility of it to gone

Comment: i dont think so... if you have array of objects you want to display in spinner, you can easier access selected ID from this array of objects, than accessing value in another spinner.