# Set a Value for Spinner Selected Item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a string array that I am trying to populate with Spinner in my android application. What I am also trying to do is that I am saving the selected Item on the device database as well as on Server. However I am converting the data on the server to JSON.

Due to this, the value that I want to save on the server is different from what I am presenting to the user. Just like we do in the HTML. For example I will display ICE Cream to the user. When the user select ICE CREAM, what should getSelected and be saved to the server should be IC instead of ICE CREAM. I have search through but could not get a head way here. I read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792159/setting-id-for-spinner-items)  but did not satisfy my need.

Can somebody please explain to me how to go about doing this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a CustomArrayAdapter for the spinner, and storing the ID in the views tag

```
view.setTag(MyIdVaraible);
```

Then when the item is selected in the spinner you can call

```
//Integer is a example, it can be any type
Integer theID = (Integer) view.getTag();
```